# My CSS in a Vue Project doesn't accept quoted URLs

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, sass

As the title says, when I pass over a quoted URL to background-image or cursor, it simply doesn't load the file. 
I work with Vue and have the **following libraries installed**: Vuetify, SASS, SASS-Loader, Node-SASS. 
I cannot uninstall Node-SASS as my project fails to run without it.

Here are some examples:

```
// This works
#app {
  cursor: url(../public/graphics/Nights_Edge.png), auto;
}
// This doesn't work
#app {
  cursor: url('../public/graphics/Nights_Edge.png'), auto;
}
// This also doesn't work
#app {
  cursor: "url(../public/graphics/Nights_Edge.png)", auto;
}
```

My follow up question is, how do I pass over such a URL with Javascript, if a quoted URL doesn't load?
What I tried to do:

```
document.getElementById("app").style.cursor = "url(../public/graphics/Nights_Edge.png) auto";
```

Obviously deleting the quote marks leaves me in a sea of red.

Comment: Your JS attempt is missing the `,` before `auto` - add that and it should work fine.

Comment: try `url("....")`

Comment: @chovy that one worked too :)

Answer (score 0):

Just to close this post. 
I have not found an answer how to fix this issue but I this work-around works for me.

```js
document.getElementById("app").style.cursor = 'unset';
```

```css
body {
  cursor: url("./image.png"), auto;
}
#app {
  cursor: auto;
}
```

with ID "app" being the child of body.

Answer (score -1):

You an escape the semantics of quotation marks within the javascript language using the `\` character.  This basically means that 'escaped' quotation marks are just treated as `"` characters in your string, instead denoting the beginning and end of the actual string in your code.  This allows you to add quotation marks in your quoted text:

```
document.getElementById("app").style.cursor = "url(\"../public/graphics/Nights_Edge.png\"), auto";
```

Comment: Tried this and a few other variations from comments under my post and sadly nothing changed. 
Could this be some kind of bug?

Comment: This still leaves the quotation marks in an invalid position:  `"url(....)"`.  It should be `url("...")`.